# How to restart Partial Login mechanism in Identity Server 3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, identityserver3, membershipreboot

### Hi everyone

#### Summary:

Our project that we develop uses Identity Server 3 in conjunction with MembershipReboot. We have next login workflow:

1. Login page (email, password)
2. Some custom User Service has override `PostAuthenticateLocalAsync` (layer after validation user credentials and before being issued a login cookie for IdentityServer) method which has our business and validation logic.
   This logic redirects the user to additional page via `AuthenticateResult` and  triggers **Partial Login** mechanism (Partial SignIn Authentication Type)
3. After success Partial Login passage (via `GetPartialLoginResumeUrlAsync`) and another login process User gets token.

This is all good work and we are happy, but here comes the problem when we need new case.

**Question:**

Our new case requires to restart login process but after Login page, that is from the moment `PostAuthenticateLocalAsync`. User does not have to reauthorize and enter credential and go directly to step **2**. In other words, we want to get Partial Login again.
How can we do this?

I will be very grateful for any advice and help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into implementing your own `ICustomRequestValidator.ValidateAuthorizeRequestAsync` and examine the incoming request. If it turns out you want to re-authenticate, you could do something like

`return Task.FromResult(new AuthorizeRequestValidationResult
{
     IsError = true
});`

Comment: I checked it and got just error page with message something like this _Custom token request validator error_ .I need to somehow skip the **Login page** and go immediately to Partial Login (where is for example 2fa). User does not have to again input their credential (login and password). Maybe I did not see or understand something...